# Shopify API returns 400 bad request when creating new custom collection

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I'm trying to create a custom collection following the [document](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-07/resources/customcollection#%5Bpost%5D/admin/api/2021-07/custom_collections.json). I'm getting a `400` about the request being malformed.

My code:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const { Shopify } = require('@shopify/shopify-api')

const client = new Shopify.Clients.Rest(
    process.env.SHOPIFY_STORE, 
    process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY
);

(async () => {
    try {
        const data = await client.post({
            path: 'custom_collections',
            body: { 'custom_collection': { 'title': 'Nike' } },
            type: 'application/json',
        })
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(err))
    }
})()
```

And the error response from Shopify is:

```
{"code":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? My tokens are correct because I can use the same token to view collections using the https URL `https://API_KEY:SECRET@SHOPIFY_STORE/admin/api/2021-07/collections.json`

Comment: Shouldn't your second parameter to the instantiation of the client object be the access token and not the api secret?

Comment: Ah maybe. Which one is the access token though? I've created private app to read data from store. It has an api key, and a secret. If I use the api key I get an unauthorized 401 error. If I use the secret I don't get the authorization error. Am I using the wrong token?

Comment: After creating the app, you can do a post to https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token to get the access token you can then use to call the api endpoints.  Check out https://shopify.dev/apps/auth/oauth to see passing in the client_id / secret and then getting back the access_token.

Comment: I've just been researching and private apps can't authenticate with an access token, instead they use Basic HTTP Authentication which is what I'm looking to do. My tool is a CLI tool for Shopify you see. https://shopify.dev/apps/auth/basic-http#shopify-access-token